# NGINX docker compose liberty REST API

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, websphere-liberty

I have docker-compose with Liberty and nginx containers but getting 404 error from nginx request call.I have

Example:
Liberty API URL :http://localhost:9082/sxrw-main/api/v1/terminals

nginx URL : http://localhost:81/sxrw-main/api/v1/terminals throwing 404 error

docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  ship-api:
    image: docker.csx.com/websphere-liberty:javaee8
    volumes:
      - ./dist/config:/config
      - ./dist/shared:/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared
    ports:
      - 9082:9080
      - 944:9443

  ship-web:
    image: docker.csx.com/nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    links:
      - ship-api
    networks:
      - shipcsx
networks:
  shipcsx:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my nginx.conf file

```
   events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
     location /sxrw-main/api {
     proxy_pass http://ship-api:9082;
    }

  }
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add ship-api to the shipcsx network. I don't think containers with a network specified also join the default network, and even with the link specified they must also share a network.

"Note: If you define both links and networks, services with links between them must share at least one network in common in order to communicate. We recommend using networks instead." from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links)

Comment: I removed link and added network still getting 404 error.

Comment: I have fixed proxy issues.I was using the wrong port in nginx default config.It should be proxy_pass http://ship-api:9080 (not 9082), but now all traffic going through liberty server .Example :localhost:81 and localhost:81/sxrw-main/api/v1/terminals.

Comment: Does it still work if you have the corrected nginx.conf but the old link config in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Yes I am good after modifying ng config .I added new location with / and root folder.